# Hanoi Algorithm With Different Nodes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, recursion

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

I need help developing a Hanoi algorithm which follows the same rules as the standard game, however the nodes that are transversed is different. In this graph Nodes represent a peg in the Hanoi algorithm. The algorithm must account for an unknown number of disks aka "n".

Given a Graph: G = {V,E}

Where V={Start,Node1,Node2,Node3,Node4,End}

Where E={(Start,Node1),(Node1,Node2),(Node2,Node3),(Node3,Node4),(Node4,End),(Node4,Node1)}

[image]

*Note: The edges above are one directional. Example: You can move from node1 to node2 but you cannot move from node1 to node4*

Using the elements of recursion, create an algorithm that solves the above Hanoi game using the graph above. What is the time complexity? The original Hanoi game has a complexity of: (2^n)-1

Comment: What are these nodes? Do they represent positions of the disks on the pegs? The original Hanoi game has a complexity of $2^n-1$ not as you stated.

Comment: No, the nodes represent pegs. The variable n represents the number of disks. The algorithm must account for all "n" integers given the limited number of nodes "aka" pegs.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding the time complexity. :)

Comment: There's some kind of mixup between ToH and the Graph that you're defining. You can think of a solution to ToH as defining a path in the state space of nodes. Now that you've given a graph, why don't you just ask for a path from start to end?

Comment: A path from start to end is only good for when the number of disks is known. A recursive algorithm on the other hand will solve the problem for a different # of disks.

Comment: You lost me, completely ;-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16727/discussion-between-ganesh-and-user127662).

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the whole stack from Start to 1 to 4 to End in the usual way, using $3(2^n-1)$ steps, so that is an upper bound.  Even without nodes 2 and 3 you have additional freedom.  You can move the whole stack to node 1 $(2^n-1$ moves), then move all but the last back to start $(2^{n-1}-1$ moves), then move the bottom all the way ($2$ moves).  This leads to a recursion $T(n+1)=(2^{n+1}-1)+(2^n-1)+2+T(n)$, but that is no better.  Another approach is to move $m$ disks to node $2$ using $2(2^m-1)$ moves, then move the remaining to 1,4,End using $3(2^{n-m}-1)$ moves, then move the $m$ disks to end using $3(2^m-1)$ moves.  This is a total of $5(2^m-1)+3(2^{n-m}-1)$ moves.  We want $5 \cdot 2^m \approx 3\cdot 2^{n-m}$ or $m+\log_2 5\approx (n-m)+\log_2 3, m \approx \frac 12(n+ \log_2 3-\log_2 5)$.  Ignoring the two logs, we get $8(2^{\frac n2}-1)$ total moves.  I don't know if there is a better strategy.

Comment: Problem, I forgot to address. In the list of Edges they are one directional. You cannot move from Node1 to Node4

Comment: Then I don't think you can do the problem at all for reasonably large $n$.  You will get stuck.  Note that in the usual tower of Hanoi the edges are bidirectional

Comment: Interesting... Well I really only need to solve between 1 to 10 anyway.

Comment: I don't think you can do more than three.  The first disk moves to 3, the second to 2, the third plays through.  If you have a fourth you are done.

Comment: Perhaps you might of drawn the graph wrong? I've updated the original post with the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way. My professor assigned this problem on the first day of class and it's blowing my mind.

Comment: The drawing is exactly what I was seeing.  I think the statement that more than three disks cannot be moved to end is correct.